# Issue importing PyVISA

Tags: python, visa

On Windows 8, Python 2.7, and [PyVISA](https://pypi.org/project/PyVISA/) 1.4:

I have tried multiple installs, most recently using `easy_install`. 
When I enter `import visa`, it seems to work, and I do not get an error message.

When I try to run  'lib = visa.VisaLibrary()', I get the following error returned:

```
>>> lib = visa.VisaLibrary()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VisaLibrary'
>>>
```

I clearly have some functionality, as the resource manager exists:

```
>>> rm = visa.ResourceManager()
>>> print(rm)
ResourceManager()
```

So, why does it seem like I do not have access to all [VISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_instrument_software_architecture) functionality?

Comment: You can check what all attributes does the module object have by calling `dir(visa)`. Use this to make sure you are not making any typo. Also use this to check if the module object has the expected attributes.

Comment: Using dir(visa), neither VisaLibrary, nor visa-library appear as attributes. Seems like a necessary attribute for core functionality though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VisaLibrary` is a function introduced in version 1.5. For 1.4, you have [`visa_library`](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=visalibrary).

To make sure everything is correct, you could run the tests; usually `pyvisa.test()`.

Comment: Neither VisaLibrary, visa_library, nor test appear to be attributes of visa. I've tried a few installs, and haven't managed to access any of these attributes

Comment: So I got it running, and I think my biggest issue was using pyvisa 1.5 commands in pyvisa 1.4. Uninstalling 1.4, rebooting and installing 1.5 and the appropriate attributes are where they should be. Thanks